# Ajax pagination in wordpress with custom post type on archive.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

Wonder if anyone can help as this is driving me insane. I have an archive page with a list of news stories. Now these news stories are controlled by an ajax call to populate and change them based on drop downs which consist of custom taxonomies (3 of them in this case, topics, sectors and technologies). Anyway the problem im having is that i cannot get pagination to work on any of the posts. I no it has something to do with the ajax call and the function its calling but i cannot get it to work. I have managed to get it to display the pagination numbers but when i click them it takes me to my web address/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php which obviously is wrong. I havent been doing this long so any help or guidance would help.

```html
  var base = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
  var technologies = document.querySelector('#category').value;
  var sectors = document.querySelector('#sectors').value;
  var topics = document.querySelector('#topics').value;
  var sort = document.querySelector('#sort').value;
  var type = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  var ajaxurl = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
                "action": "load_news",
                tech: '*' ,
                sector: '*' ,
                topic: '*' ,
                sorting: sort,
                type:type,
                base:base
        },
        success: function(response) {
           jQuery(".news-slider").html(response);
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Above is my jquery ajax call and below is the functions.php

```
                    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_news', 'prefix_load_term_news' );
                add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_news', 'prefix_load_term_news' );
                function prefix_load_term_news () {
                                $tech_id = $_GET[ 'tech' ];
                                $sector_id = $_GET[ 'sector' ];
                                $topic_id = $_GET[ 'topic' ];
                                $sort_filter = $_GET['sorting'];
                                $type = $_GET['type'];
                                $base = $_GET[ 'base' ];
                                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
                                $args = array (
                                                    'post_type' => $type,
                                                    'posts_per_page' =>2,
                                                    'paged' => $paged,
                                                    'order' => $sort_filter,
                                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                                        'relation' => 'OR',
                                                            array(
                                                                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-news',
                                                                'field'    => 'id',
                                                                'terms'    => $tech_id,
                                                            ),
                                                            array(
                                                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                                'field'    => 'id',
                                                                'terms'    => $sector_id,
                                                            ),
                                                            array(
                                                                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-topics',
                                                                'field'    => 'id',
                                                                'terms'    => $topic_id,
                                                            ),
                                                    ),
                                             );
                        try {
                            $postslist = new WP_Query($args);

                            $big = 999999999; // This needs to be an unlikely integer
                        // For more options and info view the docs for paginate_links()
                        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
                        $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big) ),
                            'current' => max( 1, $postslist->get( 'paged' ) ),
                            'total' => $postslist->max_num_pages,
                        ) );
                        // Display the pagination if more than one page is found
                        if ( $paginate_links ) {
                            echo '<div class="pagination">';
                            echo $paginate_links;
                            echo '</div><!--// end .pagination -->';
                        }
                        }
                        catch (Exception $error) {
                            echo 'An error occurred while loading news posts. Please try again.';
                        }
                        ?>
                    <?php   if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
                            while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post();
                                include('template-parts/content-archive-ajax.php');
                            endwhile;
                         wp_reset_postdata();
                 endif;
        }
```

Comment: based on this `when i click them it takes me to my web address/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php` i guess you should make `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` on your pagination link click

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax you don't have to print anything in php, yuo just put your pagination links in a php variable then you can send back it to javascript with json_encode(), so your function have to become something like this:

```
function prefix_load_term_news() {

$pagerLinks = '';
$errors = false;

$tech_id = $_GET['tech'];
$sector_id = $_GET['sector'];
$topic_id = $_GET['topic'];
$sort_filter = $_GET['sorting'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$base = $_GET['base'];
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => $sort_filter,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-news',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $tech_id,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $sector_id,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-topics',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $topic_id,
        ),
    ),
);
try {
    $postslist = new WP_Query($args);

    $big = 999999999; // This needs to be an unlikely integer
    // For more options and info view the docs for paginate_links()
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
    $paginate_links = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'current' => max(1, $postslist->get('paged')),
        'total' => $postslist->max_num_pages,
            ));
    // Display the pagination if more than one page is found
    if ($paginate_links) {
        $pagerLinks .= '<div class="pagination">';
        $pagerLinks .= $paginate_links;
        $pagerLinks .= '</div><!--// end .pagination -->';
    }
} catch (Exception $error) {
    $errors = true;
}

echo json_encode(array('errors' => $errors,'pagination' => $pagerLinks));
```

}

the PHP output in Ajax call cause an error when the javascript try to fetch the response on the success callback

Comment: Thanks for the input, i have tried implementing your example above to avail. I just end up getting this result

{"errors":false,"pagination":"
1<\/span>\n2<\/a>\n3<\/a>\n4<\/a>\nNext »<\/a><\/div>"}0

and if i then click on any of those numbers it then errors out with the url becoming the variables from the ajax call

http://website.com//wp-admin//admin-ajax.php?action=load_news&tech=%2A&sector=%2A&topic=%2A&sorting=DESC&type=news&base=%2Fnews%2F#038;tech=%2A&sector=%2A&topic=%2A&sorting=DESC&type=news&base=%2Fnews%2F&paged=3

Answer (score 0):

try to create the page link HTML by yourself in this way.

```
function prefix_load_term_news() {
    $pager_data = (object) array('curr_url' => 'yourpage_url' );
    $pagerLinks = '';
    $errors = false;

    $tech_id = $_GET['tech'];
    $sector_id = $_GET['sector'];
    $topic_id = $_GET['topic'];
    $sort_filter = $_GET['sorting'];
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $base = $_GET['base'];
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => $sort_filter,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-news',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $tech_id,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $sector_id,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-topics',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $topic_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    try {
        $postslist = new WP_Query($args);

        $big = 999999999; // This needs to be an unlikely integer
        // For more options and info view the docs for paginate_links()
        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
        $paginate_links = paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
            'current' => max(1, $postslist->get('paged')),
            'total' => $postslist->max_num_pages,
                ));

        $paginate_links = '<ul id="pagelinks">';

            if ($postslist->get('paged') > 1) {

               $paginate_links .= '<li id="first-page" class="page-numb"><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag='.($postslist->get('paged') - 1).'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>';
             } 

            if ($pager_data->max_num_pages < 6) {

                for ($p = 1; $p <= $pager_data->max_num_pages; $p++) {
                    $is_active = '';
                    if ($p == $postslist->get('paged')) {
                        $is_active = 'active';
                    }
                    $paginate_links .= '<li class="page-numb ' . $is_active . '" data-page="' . $p . '"><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag=' . $p . '">' . $p . '</a></li>';
                }
            } else {
                if ($postslist->get('paged') > 2) {

                    $paginate_links .= '<li class="dots">...</li>'
                    . '<li class="page-numb"><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag=' . ($postslist->get('paged') - 1) . '">' . ($postslist->get('paged') - 1) . '</a></li>'
                    . '<li class="page-numb active" ><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag=' . $postslist->get('paged') . '">' . $postslist->get('paged') . '</a></li>'
                    . '<li class="page-numb" ><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag=' . ($postslist->get('paged') + 1) . '">' . ($postslist->get('paged') + 1) . '</a></li>'
                    . '<li class="dots">...</li>';
                } else {
                    for ($p = 1; $p <= 5; $p++) {
                        $is_active = '';
                        if ($p == $postslist->get('paged')) {
                            $is_active = 'active';
                        }
                        $paginate_links .= '<li class="page-numb ' . $is_active . '" ><a href="' . $pager_data->curr_url . '?pag=' . $p . '">' . $p . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    $paginate_links .= '<li class="dots">...</li>';
                }
            }

            if ($postslist->get('paged') < $pager_data->max_num_pages) {

                $paginate_links .= '<li id="last-page" class="page-numb"><a  href="'. $pager_data->curr_url .'?pag='. ($postslist->get('paged') + 1).'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>';
                   } 
        $paginate_links .= '</ul>';

        // Display the pagination if more than one page is found
        if ($paginate_links) {
            $pagerLinks .= '<div class="pagination">';
            $pagerLinks .= $paginate_links;
            $pagerLinks .= '</div><!--// end .pagination -->';
        }
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        $errors = true;
    }

    echo json_encode(array('errors' => $errors,'pagination' => $pagerLinks));
}
```

the code is only an example you have to change it where is necessary to indicate the correct URL in $pager_data->curr_url. the page number in links is a GET var that i named "pag" you cat put the page number into a "data" attribute and write a jQuery function to get it and made a new ajax call to switch between pages